# Is power calculated using source voltage or load voltage?

Tags: power, current, voltage

I am making a power meter that counts the mWh over the course of a battery discharging. I am using an arduino and an INA219 current shunt module. When the load is connected, the load voltage reported drops to 3.2v, from 3.8v when there is no load. My question is, do I calculate the power with 3.2v x current, or 3.8v x current?

Comment: Do you want to know the source power (including self heating) or do you want to know the power delivered to the load?

Comment: Use a smaller shunt resistor for current sensing and be done.

Comment: Photon, I am trying to find the capacity of the battery, so which would that be?

Comment: You use both for different purposes. Add a schematic showing where you are measuring both voltages and edit the question to clarify your purpose.